# Font smoothing in Internet explorer vs Google Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

I've just taken a print screen (screen shot) of Google Chrome and zoom In the print screen image, then this is how it look like...

`Google Chrome Normal Image :`

[image: Crome image 1]

`Zoom In Image`

[image]

`More Zooming the Image`

[image]

Can any one tell the reason why `Google Chrome` use many colors to display just black text ?

I've tried the same procedure with `Internet explorer` image but they have used just black color to display black text...

This is how `Internet explorer` image look like when full zoom In...
[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleartype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn much more about the topic of text rendering in this MSDN article: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Internet Explorer's use of ClearType has changed over the years, as the product migrated from GDI to DirectWrite in Internet Explorer 9. In Windows 8, the ClearType algorithms stopped doing RGB sub-pixel positioning, moving to use greyscale only. One advantage of that change is that type still looks good when a display is rotated (as on a tablet).